# STL-like List made of linked list with nodes

Tags: c++, list, templates, linked-list

Is there a possiblity to write a template for List (like in STL) that will be made of double linked list using nodes connected to themself and to provide ability to use iterators like begin or end?
If I had nested class:

```
class Node{
        T data;
        Node* previous, next;
        Node(T &data, Node* next);
    };
```

And my list would have begin() function:

```
template<class T>
class List {
  Node *data; //first element
  ...
  public:
  T* begin() { return data->data; }; //return content of the first element
  ...
```

I assume that if I would like to use that list with for example std::copy function like

```
copy(l.begin(), l.end(), out);
```

then copy function iterates through the list using "begin++" then it would like to increment a pointer that points to the "data" object inside of node.  Then it would not take a data from next node.
So is it possible to make that kind of a list?

Comment: Why not just use `std::list` which is doubly linked?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong; you cannot use `copy` with your `begin()`, because your `begin()` returns something different from what `copy` needs.

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to write my implementation to practise

Comment: @Beta so is it possible to write a List template that behavies like this one from STL and uses linked list with nodes?

Comment: Yes, definitely, and it is a good exercise.

Comment: @Mateusz Of course.  The standard containers are written with regular C++ so you can always implement them yourself.  You may want to look at libc++ or libstdc++ to see how they implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) - which is probably what you want.

Secondly, your implementation of `begin()` does not fit the expectation for what that function returns for containers. You'll want to return something that at the very least models [`ForwardIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) (and since it's doubly-linked, [`BidirectionalIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator)). Basically, this needs to work:

```
List<int> my_list = ...;
auto it = my_list.begin();
int& x = *it;  // first value in the list
++it;          // next element in the list
int& y = *it;  // next value in the list
```

Right now, `begin()` yields a `List<int>::Node*`. That dereferences to a `List<int>::Node`, but it should dereference to an `int`. Wrong type and leaking the abstraction. Incrementing the pointer *compiles*, but it will point to some arbitrary spot in memory rather than the *next* node. There is no guarantee after all that the next node will be adjacent in memory (almost certainly it isn't!)

So you need to write your own iterator type which wraps your `Node` class, which will have to do those operations correctly based on the iterator concepts. Basically you're just mapping the iterator concept operations to what those look like for `Node`. To get you started as an example:

```
Node* underlying;

iterator& operator++() {
    underlying = underlying->next;
    return *this;
}

T& operator*() {
    return underlying->data;
}
```

Also, check out the Boost's [Iterator Facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html) library, which is helpful for writing iterators correctly.